# How to rescue Aws::AwsError: NoSuchKey

Tags: ruby, error-handling, amazon-s3

I've been struggling with this for way to long -

```
def aws_file_exists? filename
 begin
   @s3_interface.get('bucket', filename)
   return true
 catch Aws::AwsError, Aws::AwsError2, NoSuchKey, RuntimeError, AmazonError, AWSError
   return false
 end
end
```

Only, it *doesn't catch the !(*@^%@&$*%# *error*, which reports as:

```
Aws::AwsError: NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong / what is the error type that I need to be catching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this help?

```
begin
  # blah blah
rescue Aws::AwsError => ex
  return false
end
```

More importantly, it should be `begin ... rescue ... end`. You're probably confusing it with `try ... catch`.

Comment: Right, but note that it does run okay because `throw`/`catch` exists in Ruby (but isn't for exception handling),

Comment: :facepalm: @ rescue. Note - this is why I'm jealous of artists, when *they* stay up all night and start making mistakes, it's interesting, when *we* do it, it's aaaaarrrrgggggg

Comment: ...and it's why pair programming is a thing. :P